# The opposite of bitwise AND

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I don't like so many nested ifs, which is why I want the opposite of that condition `if (section_header[i].Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE)`. What would it be? I tried with `if (section_header[i].Characteristics & ~IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE) continue`, but it's not the correct one.

```cpp
for (WORD i = 0; i < nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; ++i)
{
    if (functions[i] >= section_header[i].VirtualAddress && functions[i] < section_header[i].VirtualAddress + section_header[i].Misc.VirtualSize)
    {
        if (section_header[i].Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE)
        {
            ... next
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(!(section_header[i].Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE))`?

Comment: @MikeCAT, is that the only way? I remember there was a way with bitwise NOT, but not sure how

Comment: `if ((section_header[i].Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE) == 0)`?

Comment: If `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE` is just one bit, you could do `if (~section_header[i].Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE)`, but it's less readable.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I think it worked, `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE = 0x80000000`

Comment: It seems you're looking for bitwise NAND, which doesn't exist. But `~(a & b)` <--> `(~a | ~b)` if you want.

Comment: @nop: Okay, so now you know you can.  I still say don't.  Either of `!(value & MASK)` or `(value & MASK) == 0` are more idiomatic and readable, and all three are likely to compile to the exact same code: https://godbolt.org/z/cna43vfGa

Comment: @cigien, the one Nate Eldredge mentioned worked `~a & b`. When I add the parentheses, it doesnt

Comment: @NateEldredge, can you type that as an answer, it's what I wanted. And thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are certain that your mask will only have one bit set, then you can test whether that bit is cleared (i.e. not set) in `value` by doing

```
if (~value & MASK)
    // bit is clear
```

**However, I do not recommend this.** While logically correct, it is a lot less idiomatic than the other suggested options `if (!(value & MASK))` or `if ((value & MASK) == 0)`.  People reading your code are much more likely to misunderstand, possibly leading them to create new bugs by "fixing" it.

Also, if `MASK` should have more than one bit set, the expression `~value & MASK` expression will be true if if *any* of those bits is cleared in `value`, and so it is no longer the logical negation of `value & MASK`.  For instance if `MASK == 0x3` and `value == 0x2`, then `value & MASK` is true and `~value & MASK` is also true.  By contrast `!(value & MASK)` is true iff *all* of those bits are cleared.

Answer (score 4):

Flipping your conditionals is a common practice to reduce "arrow code" (heavily indented code):

```cpp
for (WORD i = 0; i < nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; ++i) {
    if(!(section_header[i].VirtualAddress < functions[i] && functions[i] < section_header[i].VirtualAddress + section_header[i].Misc.VirtualSize)) {
        continue;
    }
    if((section_header[i].Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE) == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    // From this point
    // It's now guaranteed that selected function is in range and
    // the selected section_header contains the IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE bit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine the type of the 'Characteristics' item. Is it uint32_t? This is important, as the AND operation may get confused if you try to fuse incompatible types.

Here is how I would have done it:

```
...
auto typed_flag = (uint32_t)IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE;
if (((section_header[i].Characteristics bitand typed_flag) == typed_flag) 
{
    continue;
}
...
```

NOTE: '**bitand**' is more C++ish than ampersand (although both do exactly the same).

Comment: `bitand is more C++-ish`. No it isn't. It's an [alternative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) for character sets that don't have the proper language support. It works in both C and C++.